# definition of degree matrix of directed graph?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

im sorry if this is a trivial question. As the title stated, how is the degree matrix of a directed graph defined?
I looked up wikipedia of degree matrix but there was no defitnition of it. Instead they reffered the indegree and outdegree. I was wondering if we can represent a degree matrix of directed graph. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I have the feeling that the answer might depend on the context. Where have you encountered this matrix?

Comment: @M.Winter I’m in the situation where I need the degree and median of nodes of directed matrix. I’m working on some project about node embedding method for directed graphs.

Answer (score 2):

You just put either out- or in-degrees (whatever you like/need more) on the main diagonal.  For example in a graph with vertices $V = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and oriented edges $(1, 2)$ and $(1, 3)$ and $(2, 3)$ the out-degree matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ and the in-degree matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Note that you also can treat your graph as undirected (discard the orientation of every edge), in which case the degree matrix will be $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Which one you need depends on the particular problem you are facing, however I'm afraid I can't tell without more context.

Comment: can we combine indegree and outdegree matrix into a single matrix? lets say we want to bias the indegree matrix by adding, and subtracting for outdegree. in your example, it will be $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$. is this possible or more like preference?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ please read the following [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_matrix) (and think twice before downvoting)

Comment: @porttrum your variant might be useful in some setting like flow theory (all these max-flow min-cut theorems, you know), but more context is necessary to tell if this is the case.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ it's okay, I just don't want a useful answer to be downvoted. Actually, my first thought was the same as yours, but then I decided to google and found my answer.